# Force plot() to use specific boundaries

Tags: matlab

I want to use the 2d `plot([x1,x2,x3,x1],[y1,y2,y3,y1])` to draw a triangle in my plot image. But how do I define the borders? the Diagram should not start on the motleft point and so forth but for example on the point of origin or any other point I like to use. Also it should end where I want. How to do that?

here the full code:

```
xs = [0,10,20,0];
ys = [30,50,30,30];
plot(xs,asinh(tan(ys*pi/180)));
```

the result I wanted:

```
xs = [0,10,20,0];
ys = [30,50,30,30];
plot(xs,(asinh(tan(ys*pi/180))*180/pi));
xlim([-10 30])
ylim([-10 60])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want to set the limits of the axes of your plot so that you can place your triangle anywhere within the plot:

Try `xlim([xmin, xmax])` and `ylim([ymin, ymax])` after you run the `plot` command: see http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlim.html

If you want to know how to draw a triangle by plotting points and connecting the points:

Try simply ordering x1, x2,x3 etc in the order in which you want to connect the dots and run `plot` so that it plots lines (which I believe it does by default). But to be explicit you can run `plot([x1,x2,x3,x1],[y1,y2,y3,y1],'b-')`  to make a blue line connecting the points.